# making images communicate with each other Docker

Tags: image, docker, containers

I have created a webapp in docker. my webapp uses other docker images such as redis, mariadb. These are all up and running locally. Now I have created an image of my webapp. So I have three images : webapp(which is not up), redis and mariadb which are up.

When I tried to run image of my webapp it fails to start .. It is unable to connect with other images (redis and mariadb).

How can I make my webapp image to communicate with other required images

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using **Communication across links** which gives you also the ability to `sharing environmental variables between containers`.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/

To help you I provide you with the example of docker-compose file where images are linked together. In my example the app communicates with `database` and `redis`.

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    extends:
      service: app
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/app
    links:
      - db
      - redis
  nginx:
    extends:
      service: nginx
    links:
      - app
  redis:
    extends:      
      service: redis
  db:
    image: postgres:9
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgres
    restart: always
```

Another way is to use network commands:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a docker network to attach all the containers together.

`docker network create net`

Then you can either start the containers with the network option:

`docker run --network net ...`

or if the containers are already running, you can connect them to the network

`docker network connect net <container-name>`

Once you do that, the containers can communicate with each other using the container name as a hostname, example: redis, mongo ...

Comment: It is not working. I have a default network which has both redis and mariadb connected. Now when I do "docker run --network default webapp" it is giving error "could not connect to db" :(

Comment: @Abhishek are you naming the db container and using that name as a hostname? Also can you try to exec into one of the containers and try pinging other containers using the container name.

Comment: okay redis and mariadb are already running and I tried to ping redis from mariadb container and it can ping. but my webapp cannot ping as it is not running. I tried to run "docker run --network default webapp" but it is not starting .

Comment: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure . But if i run the webapp normally its working correctly